# Is a cubic hypersurface determined by its Fano variety of lines?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, hypersurfaces

Consider a smooth cubic complex hypersurface $X\subset\mathbf{P}^{n+1}$ of dimension $n\geqslant 3$. The associated Fano variety of lines $F(X)$ is a smooth variety of dimension $2n-4$. Can one recover $X$ from $F(X)$? The answer is positive for $n=3$ (due to Clemens-Griffiths, Tjurin) and $n=4$ (due to Voisin, I think). Are there any conjectures for general $n$?

Comment: First, you can use Lefschetz hyperplane theorems to prove that $\text{Pic}(F(X))$ is cyclic, generated by the Pluecker line bundle.  The embedding by the complete linear system of that line bundle is the embedding in the Pluecker projective space.  The intersection of all quadrics in that Pluecker space containing $F(X)$ should be the Grassmannian $\text{Grass}(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{P}^{n+1})$.  The Hilbert scheme of linear $\mathbb{P}^n$s in the Grassmannian has two components, one of which is $\mathbb{P}^n$.  Then $X$ is the set of these $\mathbb{P}^n$s intersecting $F(X)$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks for your comment, it is very helpful. In particular, you believe the answer should be positive. (I share this belief.) Do you think your argument can easily be turned into a complete proof? For instance, is it obvious from your argument that $X$ can be recovered as a scheme (and not just as a set)? Maybe you know a reference which discusses this? Or is this one of the results that are well-known among experts but no one bothered to write it down?

Comment: I will add some details below.

Comment: This is a cool argument. But for cubic fourfolds (which is all I know anything about) I think it will only be true for the *generic* $X$ that $\mathrm{Pic}(F(X))$ is cyclic? For special $X$, $F(X)$ could be  $\mathrm{K3}^{[2]}$, for instance, with large Pic?

Comment: Good point @RichardThomas. Actually, if $X$ is the Fermat cubic threefold, then $F(X)$ has maximal Picard rank, i.e. rank $h^{1,1}=25$ (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.4855.pdf , thm. 2).

Comment: $F(X)$ is given by the zero locus of a general global section of the bundle $Sym^3(R^{\vee})$ on Gr(2, n+2). So, _in general_ Lefschetz hyperplane theorem should not apply, I believe!

Comment: @Enrico.  The Picard rank of the restriction of the universal $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over $F(X)$ has Picard group $\text{Pic}(F(X))\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, since it is a (Zariski locally trivial) $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over $F(X)$.  The total space of that $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle is a complete intersection of ample divisors in the partial flag variety of "pointed lines".  You apply the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem to the total space, not to $F(X)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit.** Regarding the Picard group, since $\rho^{-1}(F(X))$ is a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over $F(X)$, the Picard group $\text{Pic}(\rho^{-1}(F(X)))$ equals $\text{Pic}(F(X))\oplus \mathbb{Z}\cdot [\pi^*\mathcal{O}(1)]$.  The fibers of the projection, $\pi:\rho^{-1}(F(X))\to X$, are complete intersections of dimension $n-3$ over $X^o$.  Thus, for $n\geq 6$, by the Grothendieck-Lefschetz theorem on Picard groups from SGA 2, also $\text{Pic}(\pi^{-1}(X^o)\cap \rho^{-1}(F(X)))$ equals $\mathbb{Z}\cdot [\rho^*\mathcal{O}(1)] \oplus \text{Pic}(X^o)$.  Since the complement of $X^o$ in $X$ has codimension $\geq 2$, also $\text{Pic}(X^o)$ equals $\text{Pic}(X)$, and this equals $\mathbb{Z}\cdot[\mathcal{O}(1)|_X]$.  If $n$ equals $5$, consider the threefolds $\pi^{-1}(\ell)\cap \rho^{-1}(F(X))$, where $\ell\subset X$ is a general line.  Intersecting with a general hyperplane $H$ gives a birational version of this threefold in the cubic fivefold $X$, and now I believe we can repeat the argument from the Griffiths-Harris proof of the Noether-Lefschetz theorem to conclude that $\pi^{-1}(\ell)\cap \rho^{-1}(F(X))$ has Picard rank $2$ (this involves analyzing the singularities of the birational version of the threefold).

**Original post.** I am adding some details to my comment, specifically the proof that the restriction homomorphism is injective, $$H^0(\text{Grass}(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{P}^{n+1}),\mathcal{O}(2)) \to H^0(F(X),\mathcal{O}(2)).$$  One proof uses the flag variety $$\text{Flag}_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^{n+1}) \subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}\times_{\text{Spec}\ k} \text{Grass}(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{P}^{n+1}),$$ with its two projections, $$\pi:\text{Flag}_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^{n+1}) \to \mathbb{P}^{n+1}, \ \ \rho:\text{Flag}_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^{n+1}) \to \text{Grass}(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{P}^{n+1}).$$  For a hypersurface $X\subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}$, for the inverse image $\pi^{-1}(X)$, the induced morphism is dominant, $$\rho:\pi^{-1}(X)\to \text{Grass}(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{P}^{n+1}),$$ and it is even flat over the open complement of the Fano scheme $F(X) = \text{Hilb}^{t+1}_{X/k}.$  Thus, the following pullback map is injective, $$H^0(\text{Grass}(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{P}^{n+1}),\mathcal{O}(2)) \to H^0(\pi^{-1}(X), \rho^*\mathcal{O}(2)).$$  Thus, it suffices to prove that the following pullback map is injective, $$H^0(\text{Grass}(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{P}^{n+1}),\mathcal{O}(2)) \to H^0(\pi^{-1}(X)\cap \rho^{-1}(F(X)),\rho^*\mathcal{O}(2)).$$  There is a maximal open subscheme $X^o\subset X$ over which the following morphism is flat of relative dimension $\leq n-d$ (in fact dimension precisely $n-d$), $$\pi:\pi^{-1}(X)\cap \rho^{-1}(F(X)) \to X.$$  It suffices to prove injectivity of the map, $$H^0(\text{Grass}(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{P}^{n+1}),\mathcal{O}(2)) \to H^0(\pi^{-1}(X^o)\cap \rho^{-1}(F(X)),\rho^*\mathcal{O}(2)).$$  For $n\geq 3$, the Fano scheme $F(X)$ is smooth of dimension $2n-4$ and $X_o$ is a dense open subscheme whose complement has codimension $\geq 2$ everywhere.

There is a sequence of Cartier divisors, $$X^o_0 = \pi^{-1}(X^o)\supseteq X^o_1 \supseteq X^o_2 \supseteq X^o_3 = \pi^{-1}(X^o)\cap \rho^{-1}(F(X)),$$ where the Cartier divisor $X^o_{e+1}$ in $X^o_e$ is the zero scheme of a section $s_{e+1}$ of the restriction to $X^o_e$ of the invertible sheaf, $$L_{3-(e+1),e+1} = \pi^*\mathcal{O}(3-(e+1))\otimes \rho^*\mathcal{O}(e+1).$$  For the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ of $\pi^{-1}(X^o)\cap \rho^{-1}(F(X))$ inside $\pi^{-1}(X^o)$, the pushforward locally free sheaf $$I_2:=\pi_*(\mathcal{I}\otimes \rho^*\mathcal{O}(2))$$ has an associated filtration that gives a short exact sequence, $$ 0\to J_2 \to I_2 \to \mathcal{O}(-(3-2))|_{X^o}, $$ where $J_2$ is the pushforward of the twist by $\rho^*\mathcal{O}(2)$ of the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{J}_1$ of $X_1^o$.  The scheme $X_1^o$ parameterizes pointed lines that are tangent to $X$ at the marked point.  The image of $X_1^o$ under $\rho$ is a dense open in a hypersurface in the Grassmannian, and the degree of that hypersurface equals $6$ (the degree of the dual curve of a plane cubic).  Since $6$ is greater than $2$, there are no global sections of $J_2$.  Also, there are no global sections of $\mathcal{O}(-1)|_{X^o}$.  Thus, there are no global sections of $I_2$.  Therefore, the only section of $\mathcal{O}(2)$ on $\text{Grass}(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{P}^{n+1})$ that vanishes on $F(X)$ is the zero section.

Comment: Many thanks for sharing your ideas. I am not yet familiar with the Griffiths-Harris proof of the Noether-Lefschetz theorem, but I shall look it up and try to check all details. This might take some time, so please bear with me.

Comment: While I haven't checked every single detail yet, I think I have read enough of the G-H proof (https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/noether.pdf, p.36 if someone want to look it up) to be convinced that their proof can be adapted to this case. Your proof of $\mathrm{Pic}(F(X))=\mathbf{Z}$ is quite slick. Another way of doing it would be to compute $b_2(F(X))=1$. In principle this should be doable by using results of Galkin-Shinder https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.5154.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, I think I now know a complete proof. I learned of this proof from D. Huybrechts's notes in progress http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/Notes.pdf, proposition 6.21.

**Theorem.** Let $X$ be a cubic hypersurface of dimension $d\geqslant 3$, with $d\neq 4$. Then $X$ can be recovered from its Fano variety of lines $F(X)$.

*Notations*: $F=F(X)$, $G=\mathrm{Gr}(2,d+2)$, $\mathscr{O}_F(1)$ and $\mathscr{O}_G(1)$ the Plücker polarisations of $F$ and $G$, respectively.

For future reference, let me state the following results.

**Lemma 1.** The canonical map $\mathrm{H}^0(G,\mathscr{O}_G(2))\rightarrow\mathrm{H}^0(F,\mathscr{O}_F(2))$ is injective.

*Proof.* See J. Starr's answer or Altman-Kleiman, Foundations of the theory of Fano schemes, proposition 1.15 (ii).

**Lemma 2.** $\omega_{F}=\mathscr{O}_{F}(4-d)$.

*Proof.* See Altman-Kleiman, proposition 1.8.

**Lemma 3.** If $V$ is a variety such that $\omega_{V}^{\vee}$ is ample, then $\mathrm{Pic}(V)$ is torsion-free.

*Proof.* Let $L$ be a torsion line bundle on $V$. Then $\mathrm{H}^i(V,L)=0=\mathrm{H}^i(V,\mathscr{O}_V)$ for $i\geqslant 1$ by Kodaira vanishing. As $\chi(L)=\chi(\mathscr{O}_V)$ by Riemann-Roch, we get $\mathrm{H}^0(V,L)=\mathrm{H}^0(V,\mathscr{O}_V)$, 
which forces $L$ to be trivial.

*Proof of the Theorem.* Let $X$ and $X'$ be cubic hypersurfaces and $f:F\xrightarrow{\sim} F'$ an isomorphism between their Fano varieties of lines. By lemma 2 we have the equality
$$(4-d)f^\ast(\mathscr{O}_{F'}(1))=f^\ast(\omega_{F'})=\omega_F=(4-d)\mathscr{O}_{F}(1)$$
in $\mathrm{Pic}(F)$. For $d\geqslant 5$ lemma 2 shows that we can use lemma 3 to deduce 
$$f^\ast(\mathscr{O}_{F'}(1))=\mathscr{O}_{F}(1).$$
For $d=3$ this is clear. The theorem then follows from proposition 4 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4509. For completeness, I repeat the proof. Let $\mathbf{P}^{d+1}=\mathbf{P}(V)$ be the ambient projective space containing $X$ and $X'$. By lemma 1,  if $Q$ is a quadric in $\mathbf{P}(\wedge^2 V)$ containing $F$, then $Q$ also contains $G$. In $\mathbf{P}(\wedge^2 V)$ the Grassmannian $G$ is cut out by quadrics, so in particular $G$ is the intersection of quadrics containing $F$. Hence there is an automorphism $g$ of $G$ taking $F$ to $F'$ via $f$, and $g$ also preserves the Plücker polarisation. By a theorem of Chow on automophisms of Grassmannians (Ann. Math. 2), $g$ is induced by an automorphism $h$ of $\mathbf{P}(V)$. The latter automorphism then induces a (polarisation-preserving) isomorphism $X\xrightarrow{\sim} X'$. (If $L$ is a line on $X$ corresponding to $[L]\in F$, then $h(L)$ is a line on $X'$, and $[h(L)]=f([L])$. Of course $X$ is covered by lines.)

Comment: Did you read the comment by Richard Thomas?  There are many different ways of embedding a K3 surface as a $(2,1)$-$(1,2)$ complete intersection surface in $\mathbb{P}^2\times \mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: You still do not understand.  For a cubic $4$fold $X$ containing two $2$-planes, the Fano scheme $F(X)$ is $\text{Hilb}^2$ of a closed subscheme $i:S\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2\times \mathbb{P}^2$ that is a $(2,1)$-$(1,2)$ complete intersection.  The image of $i$ uniquely reconstructs $X$, as I explained in my answer above.  However, there can be many ways of embedding the *same* K3 surface in $\mathbb{P}^2\times \mathbb{P}^2$ as a $(2,1)$-$(1,2)$ complete intersection.  Thus, the Fano scheme $F(X)$ does *not* determine $X$; you need the polarization.